# Poem indent every second and third line

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, page-layout

Is there a way, in InDesign, to indent every second and third line in a poem to look like this?!

[image]

Comment: Hi Mona, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed)

Comment: As Ryan asks, could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, by using "next styles" – a feature of Paragraph Styles.**

First the preparation: at the end of each line in your poem should be a hard return, meaning each line is it's own paragraph.

Then create three paragraph styles: one for each of the first three lines. Paragraph style #1 has no left indent, #2 has a small left indent, and #3 has a big indent.

Now link the styles together:

- Edit paragraph style #1, and set its "Next style" to paragraph style #2.
- In the same fashion, set the next style of style #2 to #3.
- And finally set the next style of #3 to #1.

Each style now "points to" the style that should follow it.

To apply:

- Select all the text
- In your paragraph styles palette, right-click (or control-click) your paragraph style #1
- And from the menu that appears, choose "**Apply paragraph style #1, then Next Style**"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try "nested styles" for indesign.

Comment: Hi user44834, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit? Why is this the right method, and how would one apply it to solve the question? Thanks! If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!